# The requested URL is not found in Server (Ubuntu)

Tags: apache, codeigniter, http, ubuntu

I want to setup my web app on a server, and besides the home page, all pages have this error:

Not Found
The requested URL XXXXXX was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at http://www.XXXXXXX.com Port 80

My htaccessfile looks like this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
AllowOverride All # default if <= 2.3.8
Options All # this is the default
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

I developed this web app using codeigniter, works fine with my localhost.

Please note: I am still new to deploying web apps in servers, so I hope you can help.

**UPDATE**
I am now able to run my web app, however, I cannot access one page. Just one page. And the error says: server is unable to handle this request http error 500

Comment: I already edited the Apache config for the virtual host, and set it to AllowOverride All, but still I get this error.

Comment: 1. check your domain is working well. upload a sample html file  to the server and try the domain, if it works let me know

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Then it is your domain issue, not CodeIgniter, please try to map the domain with your IP address properly, before that you should try with IP address is redirecting to the working folder

Comment: Thanks all good now. But I am now unable to access some parts of my website....